# Clipping raster data with shapefile in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, clip, error-000800

Am trying to clip a raster data to the extent of the input shapefile but I keep getting an the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\dealingwithraster.py", line 40, in <module>
arcpy.Clip_management("outputRaster","#","outputclip","input_studyArea","ClippingGeometry","MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13771, in Clip
raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Clip). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of ClippingGeometry | NONE.
Failed to execute (dealingWithRaster)
```

Below is the my code:

```
import arcpy
input_raster= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
input_studyArea= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outputRaster = Con(inRas1>=0 ,inRas1,1)
outputRaster.save(outputgdb + rasterName)
arcpy.Clip_management("outputRaster","#","outputclip","input_studyArea","ClippingGeometry","MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Comment: This is probably just a part of your larger workflow, but shouldn't you pass the `outputRaster` variable instead of the string `"outputRaster"` to the `Clip` tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems that I can see, you'll need to fix these for your script to work:

1. Your have put quotemarks around your variables in the `arcpy.Clip_management()` line, so now they're just strings.
   `"outputRaster"` should be `outputRaster`, `"input_studyArea"` should be `input_studyArea` etc.
2. You have no variable `inRas`, but you're using that variable in `outputRaster = Con(inRas1>=0 ,inRas1,1)`
3. You have no variable `rasterName`, but you're using that variable in `outputRaster.save(outputgdb + rasterName)`
4. You have no variable `outputclip` - what is this, as you've also quoted it `"outputclip"`

Comment: that was just part of the code i was working on, so other parts were not included.

Comment: i removed the quotemarks and it worked. thank again